# Size of components in a JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

Ian trying to create a panel with a title at the top and a few JTextFields and JLabels however when I put the First JLabel in and a JTextField no matter what I change the size to or change the coordinates on the panel it doesn’t change size or place.

```
    JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
  Panel2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
Frame.add(panel2);
    Panel2.setBounds(100,100,250,200);

    JLabel label2 = new      JLabel(“NutriGYM”)
    Label2.setSize(200,200);
    Pane.add(label2);

    JTextField Weight = new        JTextField();
    Weight.setBounds(0,0,250,250);
    Panel2.add(label2);
```

Comment: Swing more or less expects you **not** to specify bounds, but to use Swing layout managers. Read through the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more information.

Comment: And the layout managers don't respect size for the most part. Instead, most look for the component's preferred size. Consider overriding getPreferredSize.

Comment: BTW despite not recommended, you can `panel.setLayout(null);` and do the layout yourself, setting size and location of every component in that panel. Usually that gets *messy* very fast (window being resized, different display resolutions, different scales, font size, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into setting the layout of your container. For example:

```
public void run() {
  JFrame = new JFrame("Title");
  Container content = frame.getContentPane();
  content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

  JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
  JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue");

  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  buttons.add(continueButton, c);

  content.add(buttons, c);
}
```

In the above code snippet, I first created a JFrame and set the layout of its Content Pane to GridBagLayout() (other examples of layouts include BorderLayout() and others which I recommend you look into to decide which one you like most). Then I initialized my GridBagConstraints which essentially acts like a coordinate system for the JFrame content pane. I initialized my first button at (0, 0) in my JPanel, then I assigned my entire JPanel to (0,0) in my content pane. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. Notice that when you resize the main panel, the label and textbox get repositioned.  It is best to use one of the layout managers rather than use absolute positioning.  In this example, the [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) manager is used and is the default for `JPanels`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class UsingLayout extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new UsingLayout());
    }

    public UsingLayout() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.white); // main panel
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        add(panel2);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("NutriGYM");
        label2.setFont(font);
        panel2.add(label2);

        JTextField weight = new JTextField();
        weight.setFont(font);
        weight.setColumns(10); // setting columns instead of size
        panel2.add(weight);
        
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,500);
    }

}
```

Note:  Instead of setting the size for the `JLabel` and `JTextField`, you may just want to set the [Font](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html) you are using.  In the above, the two components match and line up.  Of course, setting the preferred size is also an option depending on your design considerations.